# outbound web requests fail when made from IIS sites using shared IP address

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7.5

- IIS 7.5 / Windows Server 2008 R2
- Multiple IIS sites bound to the same IP address, using host names.
- Inbound traffic to sites working fine.
- Outbound web requests made by the back-end site code fail. Remote site returns 404 (NotFound).
- Verified via a network trace that the traffic is making it to the remove server.
- Same requests work fine if done from a site using a dedicated IP address (i.e. not shared w/ any other sites).

Anyone have any ideas on how to make this work or what could be going wrong?

Network trace on hosting server:

Successful request from site w/ non-shared IP address:

```
No.     Time            Source                Destination           Protocol Info
   6366 15:54:35.590463 192.168.1.76          173.194.77.121        HTTP     GET /key/value/one/two HTTP/1.1 
   6369 15:54:35.599879 173.194.77.121        192.168.1.76          TCP      http > 55407 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=110 Win=344 Len=0
   6370 15:54:35.621587 173.194.77.121        192.168.1.76          HTTP     HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (application/json)
   6608 15:54:35.815774 192.168.1.76          173.194.77.121        TCP      55407 > http [ACK] Seq=110 Ack=357 Win=509 Len=0
```

Failed request from site using a shared IP address:

```
No.     Time            Source                Destination           Protocol Info
   9720 15:54:39.244192 192.168.1.80          173.194.77.121        HTTP     GET /key/value/one/two HTTP/1.1 
   9760 15:54:39.256958 173.194.77.121        192.168.1.80          TCP      [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   9761 15:54:39.256962 173.194.77.121        192.168.1.80          HTTP     HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  (text/html)
   9762 15:54:39.257027 192.168.1.80          173.194.77.121        TCP      55438 > http [ACK] Seq=212 Ack=1676 Win=512 Len=0
```

Code:

```
public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string method = "GET", string referer = null, string contentType = null, int timeout = 100000, string authentication = null, string bindToIpAddress = null, string host = null)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bindToIpAddress))
    {
        IPAddress bindIp;
        if (!IPAddress.TryParse(bindToIpAddress, out bindIp))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("bindToIpAddress");
        }

        request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = ((sp, rep, rc) =>
        {
            return new IPEndPoint(bindIp, 0);
        });
    }

    request.Accept = "*/*";
    request.ContentType = contentType;
    request.Referer = referer;
    request.Method = method;
    request.Timeout = timeout;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(host))
    {
        request.Host = host;
    }

    return request;
}

string GetData()
{
    try
    {
        string result;

        var request = CreateWebRequest("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", 
                                       "GET", 
                                       "somedomain.com", 
                                       timeout: (10 * 1000), 
                                       bindToIpAddress: "192.168.27.133" /*site IP*/);

        request.Accept = "application/json";

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Silly question but is the dedicated and shared IP addresses coming from the same ISP? 
Is there any chance that your shared IP is blacklisted perhaps?

Comment: Yes.  Same ISP and hosting environment, Rackspace, for both IPs.  Blacklisted where?  By external service?  Happens with all 3rd party web services we have tried.  I don't think they would all be blacklisting the IP?

Comment: Have you done an IISReset after switching the IP's from Dedicated to Shared?

Comment: Yes. Have rebooted the server.

Comment: My guess is that the response from the service is making it to your server but NOT to the site because the communication is done by IP, not Hostname.

Does any of your sites have a binding using the IP as well?
If so - then probably that site is receiving the response and not the one you would expect?
If not - add a binding using the IP and try again.

Comment: 404 shows some config issues, check host headers, rules, routing if exists.

Comment: Looks like this line: 9761 15:54:39.256962 173.194.77.121        192.168.1.80          HTTP     HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  (text/html) tells us that the remote server is trying to reach back your server, using IP but there's not site there to reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in our application. In some cases, the host header (Host property on the request) was being set improperly (to the hosting/source site's host name). The stripped down code sample in the question doesn't show it. It was fine for web services that ignored the header and was an issue (404 response) for others that did *not* ignore the header. The issue had nothing to do w/ IIS or shared IP address. Thanks for all of the responses.

Answer (score 0):

The 404 response comes back from the remote site, so the remote site is failing to process your request, and it has nothing to do with what's going on on your local server.

The only difference from the remote site's point of view is the sender's IP address, so it must be configured to accept requests only from certain IP addresses. This restriction could be in the remote server, or any firewall, router or proxy in between.